# ReactiveSwift error after update to Xcode12( Error msg: Cannot convert value of type 'Disposable?' to closure result type 'Void')

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, reactive, reactive-swift

The following func runs well before I update to Xcode12, I'm new to ReactiveSwift and I don't know how to fix this issue, thanks for you help!

[image]

Error message: Cannot convert value of type 'Disposable?' to closure result type 'Void'

```
 public func testFunc(input: Signal<Value, Never>.Event = .completed) -> Signal<Value, Never> {

    return Signal<Value, Never> { observer, lifetime in
        return self.signal.observe { event in
            switch event {
            case .value(let value):
                observer.send(value: value)
            case .failed(_):
                observer.send(input)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your return type, initializer requires `(Observer, Lifetime) -> Void` bug you give it `(Observer, Lifetime) -> Disposable?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a change made in newer `ReactiveSwift` versions. Instead of returning a disposable, you should add it to the `lifetime` passed to the closure:

```
public func testFunc(input: Signal<Value, Never>.Event = .completed) -> Signal<Value, Never> {

    return Signal<Value, Never> { observer, lifetime in
        lifetime += self.signal.observe { event in
            switch event {
            case .value(let value):
                observer.send(value: value)
            case .failed(_):
                observer.send(input)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like there are also some missing cases in that `switch` statement though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Using your code I try to delete `lifetime +=` It's also no error in it,    Does it make a difference? (I delete some case for better readability, It's ok)

Comment: In your closure, you're observing `this.signal`. If you want that observation to be cancelled when the current signal finishes, then you need to use `lifetime +=`. Otherwise the observation will continue indefinitely.